# Scala Error convert type mismatch; found : () ⇒ Iterator[Long] required: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[?]

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, akka-stream

I have a function

`

```
def getFollowers(userId: Long): Try[Set[Long]] = {
      Try({
        val followerIds = mutable.Set[Long]()
        var cursor = -1L
        do {
          val client = AkkaStreamTwitterClient()
          val res = client.friendsFollowers().getFollowersIDs(userId, cursor, 5000)
          res.getIDs.toList.foreach(x => followerIds.add(x))
          if (res.hasNext) {
            cursor = res.getNextCursor
          }
          else {
            cursor = -1 // Exit the loop
          }
        } while (cursor > 0)
          val immutableFollower = scala.collection.immutable.Set(followerIds.toSet.toArray:_*)
          immutableFollower         
      })
    }
```

`

The function is called from

`

```
Source(() =>
 AkkaStreamTwitterHelper.getFollowers(userId).get.toIterable.iterator)
  .grouped(100)
  .map(x => AkkaStreamTwitterHelper.lookupUsers(x.toList))
  .mapConcat(identity(_))
  .runForeach(x => output.offer(x.getScreenName))
  .onComplete({
    case _ =>
      Console.println(s"Fetched ${output.size()} profiles")
      val endTime = System.nanoTime()
      Console.println(s"Time taken: ${(endTime - startTime)/1000000000.00}s")
      system.terminate()
      Runtime.getRuntime.exit(0)
  }) (ec)
}
```

`

The line "source" gives an error

Scala Error convert type mismatch; found : () ⇒ Iterator[Long] required: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[?]

I code from

http://blog.abhinav.ca/blog/2015/02/19/scaling-with-akka-streams/

Answer (score 0):

You might need `Source.fromIterator` depending on your version.

```
Source.fromIterator(() =>
  AkkaStreamTwitterHelper.getFollowers(userId).get.toIterator)
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the error except but moving same error to line .  .mapConcat(identity(_)) .

Answer (score 0):

By using `getFollowers(userId).get.toIterable.iterator` you've got a funtion that returns an interator: `() => Iterator`, not the iterator itself. You need to apply this function (simply change it to `getFollowers(userId).get.toIterable.iterator()`)

Comment: The error changes to "Iterator[Long] does not take parameters"